# rxbag extraction of frames

Tags: ros, rosbag, rxbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone !

I was wondering is there is any steps to follow in order to save all the frames that I put into a rosbag on my computer with **rxbag**.

I noticed that there is a button "save frames" when you open it with the following :
"View (by type) -> sensor_msgs/Image->stereo/left/image_rect "

I'm able to "select" the frames or should I say the Timeline in the default menu of rxbag (because it's written at the bottom of the image_viewer that it "Save frames from selected region") but it seems to have no effect when I click on the "save frames" button.

any hints ?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38073/rxbag-extraction-of-frames/) by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found it!

In order to use rxbag (much more efficient than the extract_image node => did not extract all the images of my bags files) you have to :

1°) select with your mouse the length of your timeline (a slightly cyan color show up as you select it)

2°) play your bag file (let it run)

3°) select the view "image"

4°) click on the button on the right of the text "frame%04d.png"

5°) And here normaly pop's up an another window that offers you to save all the frames

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) with karma: 91 on 2012-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you just want all the frames from a bag file?

In that case I would use rosbag instead of rxbag ad follow the description [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data)

---

Originally posted by [NsN](https://answers.ros.org/users/1786/nsn/) with karma: 95 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent_V](https://answers.ros.org/users/2175/vincent_v/) on 2012-07-06**:
I knew that technique but it seems that it does not extract all the images when you saved them with a specific frame rate. So if you don't recompile the all extract_images.cpp with the specific framerate it does not work well.
That's why I was looking for an another solution at this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/27713/how-to-recover-the-saved-images-in-a-bagfile-to/#27716) answer that uses [rospy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy) and the [rosbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1